# Problema al iniciar wildfly con standalone

Tags: wildfly

Acabo de realizar la instalación de Wildfly, pero al lanzar el comando
wildfly_31\bin\standalone.conf.bat me da error.
He revisado [una guía](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=389:configurar-java-en-windows-variables-de-entorno-javahome-y-path-cu00610b&catid=68&Itemid=188) bastante sencilla, pero no hay manera.

```
Calling "D:\wildfly_31\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe\bin\java.exe" does not exist
```

Entiendo por la línea que sale, que está llamando dos veces a java.exe de una forma un tanto rara y que debería ser únicamente C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\bin\java.exe

He configurado la variable JAVA_HOME en Variables de entorno de la siguiente forma

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\
```

Y lo mismo con Path

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Lo que no entiendo es, por qué si está puesto correctamente, está saliendo de esa forma cuando se llama al .bat

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda. :D